# Can't convert json object to 2D array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a JSON object:

```
var info=JSON.parse(server_response);
```

I run `console.log(info);`
And got this output:

```
[  
  [  
    [  
      "Dipu",
      "Mondal",
      "O Positive",
      "017xxxx",
      "AIS"
    ]
  ],
  [  
    [  
      "dipu",
      "Roy",
      "O Positive",
      "017xxxx",
      "Electrical"
    ]
  ],
  [  
    [  
      "Dhinka",
      "Chika",
      "O Positive",
      "9038485777",
      "stat"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Following this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6CGh8/ I tried :

```
console.log(info.length); //output: 161
console.log(info[0].length); //output: 1
console.log(info[0][1]); //output: undefined
```

Whereas expected output of these 3 lines (respectively):

> 3
> 5
> Dipu

Why I expect this:

This JSON object contains 3 arrays, 5 data in each array, and `[0][1]`th element is `Dipu`.

How can I get my expected output?

Comment: This is not an issue, it is printing correctly. Your array is wrapped inside another array. To get `dipu` you would need to look for `info[0][0][1]`, as your m,ain array contains an array of arrays that contain the data...

Comment: _we have to go deeper_ `console.log(info[0][0][0]); // output: Dipu`.. you have another array inside your array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have json encoded twice and so info is just a text and not an array.

```
info.length    // length of the string
info[0].length // length of a character (1)
info[0][1]     // undefined because a character is not an array
```

Try `var info = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(server_response))`

Comment: Nice catch! That fits the evidence perfectly.

Comment: *"Try `var info = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(server_response))`"* Or better yet, fix the server so it doesn't double-encode the string.

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in your understatement and JSON structure.

1. Your JSON data is bounded in array twice that's not needed(That will correct the first tow requirements)
2. info[0][1] is not *Dipu* its *Mondal* actually. info[0][1] means second element of the array info[0]. You need to change that to info[0][0] to access first element of first array i.e, *Dipu*

Your JSON Structure needs to be modified to

```
[["Dipu","Mondal","O Positive","017xxxx","AIS"],
 ["dipu","Roy","O Positive","017xxxx","Electrical"],
 ["Dhinka","Chika","O Positive","9038485777","stat"]]
```

Here is the sample code snippet

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script>
        var info = JSON.parse('[["Dipu","Mondal","O Positive","017xxxx","AIS"],["dipu","Roy","O Positive","017xxxx","Electrical"],["Dhinka","Chika","O Positive","9038485777","stat"]]');
        console.log(info.length); //OP: 3
        console.log(info[0].length); //OP: 5
        console.log(info[0][0]); //OP: Dipu
    </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```